# How to plot and calculate the square of a figure obtained as the result of intersections of functions?

Tags: plotting

Let's say we have a list of functions:

```
y = 4/Sqrt[4 - x^2],
y = 4, 
y = 6/(x + 5), 
y = Abs[x],
x >= -2
```

The simple plot of these functions:

```
Plot[{4/Sqrt[4 - x^2], 4, 6/(x + 5), Abs[x]}, {x, -2, 5}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

And here is my best attempt to get the region derived by intersections:

```
Plot[{4/Sqrt[4 - x^2], 4, 6/(x + 5), Abs[x]}, {x, -5, 5}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y},Reduce[x >= -2 && y <= 4 && y >= 6/(x + 5) &&y >= Abs[x]]],Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

Here is the desired figure:

[image]

> 1. Is there any way to plot functions and inequalities on the same chart?
> 2. Is there any way to plot and calculate the squares of figures obtained by intersections of functions?

Comment: How are you picking the intersections and regions?

Comment: The only one possible region that could be constructed by intersections of all the functions: http://res.cloudinary.com/invimind/image/upload/q_100/v1478804588/1_cet1g6.png

Comment: I think you are after [`RegionPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html); see `RegionPlot[
 Reduce[x >= -2 && y <= 4 && y >= 6/(x + 5) && y >= Abs[x]], {x, -2, 
  4}, {y, 0, 4}]`. Note, however, that `FunctionDomain[4/Sqrt[4 - x^2], x]` yields `-2 < x < 2`, so `RegionPlot[Reduce[x >= -2 && y <= 4 && y >= 6/(x + 5) && y >= Abs[x] && 
    y <= 4/Sqrt[4 - x^2]], {x, -2, 4}, {y, 0, 4}]` will fail.

Comment: So how can I overcome that? I don't quite understand, why even such expression as `RegionPlot[Reduce[y <= 4/Sqrt[4 - x^2]], {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 4}]` yields an error

Comment: `Reduce` in not needed here; see `RegionPlot[
 x >= -2 && y <= 4 && y >= 6/(x + 5) && y >= Abs[x] && 
  y <= 4/Sqrt[4 - x^2], {x, -2, 4}, {y, 0, 4}]`. The region $x\in(2,4)$ is empty because, via `&&`, the conditions are a logical conjuction; in that interval `4/Sqrt[4 - x^2]` doesn't exist, so the whole condition is `False`, so `RegionPlot` won't plot anything there. You'd have to separately add what you want to achieve in that region, e.g. `RegionPlot[
 2 <= x <= 4 && y <= 4 && y >= Abs[x], {x, -2, 4}, {y, 0, 4}]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are after a `RegionPlot` in this case.

```
RegionPlot[
 x >= -2 && y <= 4 && y >= 6/(x + 5) && y >= Abs[x] && 
  y <= 4/Sqrt[4 - x^2] && 2 <= x <= 4 && y <= 4 && 
  y >= Abs[x], {x, -2, 4}, {y, 0, 4}]
```

gives an empty plot; this is because

```
FunctionDomain[4/Sqrt[4 - x^2], x]
```

> -2 < x < 2

so the function does not exist (in reals) in the region $x\in (2,4)$. `4/Sqrt[4 - x^2] /. x -> 3` gives `-((4 I)/Sqrt[5])`, and there is no order among the complex numbers so you can't choose values smaller than this. The region specification is a logical conjunction, so the condition `y <= 4/Sqrt[4 - x^2]` yields `False` in $x\in (2,4)$, hence the whole conjunction is `False` and so `RegionPlot` won't plot anything there. Therefore (note the "or": `||`)

```
RegionPlot[(-2 <= x <= 2 && y <= 4 && y >= 6/(x + 5) && y >= Abs[x] &&
     y <= 4/Sqrt[4 - x^2]) || (2 <= x <= 4 && y <= 4 && 
    y >= Abs[x]), {x, -2, 4}, {y, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

gives the desired output.

---

Additionally, as a display of the line of reasoning, consider the disjoint regions separately:

```
plot1 = RegionPlot[
  x >= -2 && y <= 4 && y >= 6/(x + 5) && y >= Abs[x] && 
   y <= 4/Sqrt[4 - x^2], {x, -2, 4}, {y, 0, 4}]

plot2 = RegionPlot[
  2 <= x <= 4 && y <= 4 && y >= Abs[x], {x, -2, 4}, {y, 0, 4}]

GraphicsRow[{plot1, plot2}]
```

[image]